# No Read Committed Snapshot in ADO.NET Isolation Level?

Tags: asp.net, sql, ado.net, sql-server-2012

Checking the ADO.NET [IsolationLevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.isolationlevel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), I have found that there is no Read_Commited_Snapshot. How to set this level of IsolationLevel using ADO.NET

Answer (score 2):

Read_Commited_Snapshot is not an isolation level, its a database option which makes statements with the read committed isolationlevel using row versioning. I don't think you should set that in ADO.net. Rather set it in the SQL Server environment by sqlcmd or SSMS, ADO.Net will use the read committed by default so there's probably no need for changes of the transatiction level at all.

Comment: If you're using Entity Framework you can try using the ExecuteSqlCommand in your Context, ex. context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON"), however you will need sufficient permissions in SQL Server to do so